# Dungeon Defenders Local Split Screen

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I recently purchased Dungeon Defenders from Steam to be able to play it with my friends locally. We have simply want to be able to do local split screen with several controllers and a keyboard.

This morning I set up the controllers, and I started a split screen game, and it all worked just as expected, with one small exception - every hero we created was linked to one 'master' account. All mana gained, and all items picked up were all shared between the heroes.

This simply won't work, so is there some way to get split-screen working properly with steam, or is there some way to gain an original copy of the game via my steam licence?

Comment: This seems like a bug in the steam version, I played the game splitscreen quite a bit with three friends using the xbla version. I have never encountered anything like what you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking on both the steam forums, and contacting trendy games, it appears that isn't a but, but instead a "feature". Not sure what the point is of split-screen if you're still only playing one player's characters, but that's the way it is.

Comment: I think it's to do with the limitations of Steam functionality - one steam account at a time in use, etc?

Comment: I've just confirmed that with several others. I'm currently making a simple mod that binds mana and items with the Hero instead of the User.